# Include semicolon in preamble definition for tikz macro?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, best-practices

Say I define a macro `\arr` in the preamble for use in a `tikzpicture`. Is it best practice to:

**Exclude** the semicolon from the definition and include it in the `tikzpicture`,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\arr}[2]{\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- ({#1},{#2}) }
                                    % no semicolon here ^

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \arr{2}{1};  % semicolon here
  \arr{4}{-3}; % semicolon here
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

or

**Include** the semicolon in the definition and exclude it from the `tikzpicture`,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\arr}[2]{\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- ({#1},{#2});}
                                    %    semicolon here ^

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \arr{2}{1}  % no semicolon here
  \arr{4}{-3} % no semicolon here
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

?

I am leaning towards including the semicolon in the definition, as it generalises to macros containing more than one drawing command. Yet when the macro is then used in a `\foreach` loop, still a semicolon needs to be added when it is called, which seems redundant but is necessary to avoid errors.

Comment: Re `\foreach`: Not really, if you have one than more paths in a loop block or not a path with `;` directly in the code, you have to/should use braces, e.g. `\foreach \x in {…} {\arr{2}{1}}` — An extra `;` in a TikZ picture doesn't hurt anybody (you get an "Missing character" line in the log file, though). There is also a more flexible key solution: `\tikzset{arr/.style 2 args={-latex, insert path={(0,0)--({#1},{#2})}}}`, then you can use `\draw[arr={2}{1}];` and `\draw[blue,arr={4}{-3}];`or even `\draw[red] [arr={3}{-1}] -- ++ (left:1);`. The same holds for the semicolon-less definition.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for the `\foreach` tips and the key solution. Is `\tikzset` versatile enough to do more than one drawing command e.g. "draw a circle with centre `({#1},{#2})` and then draw an arrow from `({#1},{#2})` to `({#3},{#4})`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's no real best practice here, let's look at the two possibilities: if you *don't* use the semicolon inside the definition of `\arr` and you forget inside the `tikzpicture` you'll get an error:

```
\newcommand*{\arr}{\draw (0,0) -- (1,1)}% No semicolon in definition
\begin{tikzpicture} \arr  \end{tikzpicture}% Forgoten semicolon → "Giving up on this path..."
\begin{tikzpicture} \arr; \end{tikzpicture}% With semiconlon → Ok
```

If you *do* put it in the definition wheter or not you place the semicolon after the command the code will compile. In the case where there's extra semicolons you'll get a "Missing character" message in the log file.

```
\newcommand*{\arr}{\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);}% Semicolon in definition
\begin{tikzpicture} \arr  \end{tikzpicture}% Forgoten semicolon → Ok
\begin{tikzpicture} \arr; \end{tikzpicture}% With semiconlon → "Missing character"
```

So, worst case scenario is getting the usual "`Giving up on this path`" error. In my personal opinion, I do not put the semicolons inside the definition because I'm used to always putting them on the end of lines, and I like the code to be consistent.

---

As in the matter of the `insert path` key, it inserts the specified path wherever the key is called upon. So whatever path you put in there, will be called when the key is called. You can say, for instance:

```
\tikzset{
  arr/.style args={circle at #1 to arrow at #2}{
    ->,
    insert path={#1 circle[radius=2mm] -- #2}
  }
}
\tikz \draw[arr={circle at (0,0) arrow at (1,1)];
```

Other ways to define styles, like `/.style n args={<n>}{style}` can also be used and are extensively documented in the Ti*k*Z manual.